# What do the clavinova model numbers tell me?

Tags: instruments, digital-piano

When shopping for a used clavinova I tried to figure out which models are a good choice for me. Doing that, I quickly wondered what the CLP-model numbers are trying to tell me.

For the most recent years the model numbers are:

- 2006: CLP-220, CLP-230, CLP-240, CLP-270, CLP-280, CLP-265GP, CLP-295GP
- 2008: CLP-320, CLP-330, CLP-340, CLP-370, CLP-380, CLP-S306, CLP-S308
- 2011: CLP-430, CLP-440, CLP-465GP, CLP-470, CLP-480, CLP-S406, CLP-S408
- 2014: CLP-525, CLP-535, CLP-545, CLP-575, CLP-585

**What do these numbers stand for?**

Answer (score 2):

### Here's how you read the model numbers for the last ten years

**first digit -> year**
The first digit tells you from which year the instument is.
**2**.. means **2005**: CLP-**2**20, CLP-**2**30, CLP-**2**40, CLP-**2**70, CLP-**2**80
 
**3**.. means **2007**: CLP-**3**20, CLP-**3**30,...

**second digit -> quality/features**
The second digit tells you how high its quality is compared to the other models of that year
CLP-2**2**0 **<** CLP-2**3**0 **<** CLP-2**4**0 **<** CLP-2**7**0 **<** CLP-2**8**0
CLP-3**2**0 **<** CLP-3**3**0 **<** ...

---

**exceptions from the rule** (of course)
Careful though, some older models ar using the same first digits: 
CLP-200 (1986), CLP-250 (1988), CLP-260 (1990)
CLP-300 (1986), CLP-311 (1996), CLP-360 (1990)
CLP-411 (1996)
CLP-500 (1987), CLP-511 (1996), CLP-550 (1988), CLP-555 (1997), CLP-560 (1990), CLP-570 (1989)